# Can this grammar be simplified?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-sensitive

So, I have a book here, which has an example for context sensitive grammar, and the grammar is the famous $0^n1^n2^n$ , and it has:

$$ \begin{align}
S  &\rightarrow 0BS2 \mid 012 \\
B0 &\rightarrow 0B \\
B1 &\rightarrow 11 \\
\end{align} $$

I agree that the above works, but what is wrong with just saying:
$S\rightarrow 0S12 |\epsilon$

The above also generators the same number of $0$s as $1$s and $2$s.

Answer (score 5):

Your grammar will generate:
$S\rightarrow 0S12\rightarrow 00S1212\rightarrow 001212$ which is not in the required language.

Answer (score 2):

By one definition, context sensitive grammars have productions $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$, where the length of $\beta$ can't be less than the length of $\alpha$. This rules out your alternative grammar outright.